# How to use counter inside Parfor matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have the following loop and I get an error at `MachPoints` saying: `"Valid indices for MachPoints are restricted in PARFOR loops"` and `parfor cannot run due to the way the variable is used`

```
some previous code declaring A,B,C..

if Case == 4
    rng(1);

Initial_Vx        = some number
Initial_Vy        = some number
Initial_Vz        = some number

Initial_X         = some number
Initial_Y         = some number
Initial_Z         = some number

WVelocity_X       = some number
WVelocity_Y       = some number
WVelocity_Z       = some number

WError_X          = some number
WError_Y          = some number
WError_Z          = some number

parfor Monte = 1:5


    Wind_Velocity     = [WVelocity_X WVelocity_Y WVelocity_Z];      
    Wind_Error        = [WError_X WError_Y WError_Z];               


    Launch_Error      = some number;                                                   

    Initial_Velocity  = [Initial_Vx Initial_Vy Initial_Vz]*(Launch_Error/100); 
    Initial_Position  = [Initial_X Initial_Y Initial_Z];                       

    Rotation          = 0.00;                                                 

    Global_Consts      = {A, B, C, D, E, F};
    Initial_Conditions = {Initial_Velocity, Initial_Position, Wind_Velocity, Wind_Error};


    Fig_Num = 1;
    k = 1;   
    for MachP = [0.5:0.01:0.95, 1.2:0.01:3.5]   
        if MachP < 1.2
            [Xcp_Total, Lift_Canard, MRoll_Canard, My_Canard, Sim_Parameters] = FIN_SUB(MachP);
        else
            [Xcp_Total, Lift_Canard, MRoll_Canard, My_Canard, Sim_Parameters] = FIN_SUP(MachP);
        end
        Cln_alpha_M(k)  = Sim_Parameters(1);
        Clc_alpha_M(k)  = Sim_Parameters(2);
        Clw_alpha_M(k)  = Sim_Parameters(3);
        Clb_alpha_M(k)  = Sim_Parameters(4);
        MachPoints(k)   = MachP;
        k = k + 1;
    end
    Parameters = Sim_Parameters(5:25);   
    [Position,Initial_Conditions,Tgo] = GFunction(MachPoints,Cln_alpha_M,Clc_alpha_M,Clw_alpha_M,Clb_alpha_M,Parameters);

    Final_Position(1,:) = Position{1,1}(end,:);
    Whole_Traj{Monte} =  Position{1,1};
    Miss(Monte) = sqrt(sum((Final_Position(1,:)).^2));

    Delta_X(Monte) = Final_Position(1,1) - 0;
    Delta_Y(Monte) = Final_Position(1,2) - 0;

    IC{Monte} = Initial_Conditions;
    Tgo_Data{Monte} = Tgo{1,1}(:,1);

end

Mean_Miss = mean(Miss);

end
```

Thank you

Comment: In your code the second iteration of the `parfor` loop has to continue with the `k` calculated by the previous iteration. This is not possible because both iterations might run in parallel. Something seems wrong with your code besides the `parfor`, the outputs a and b are never used.

Comment: I tried a different to avoid that second iteration but it still dont work. a,b,data1,data2 are just simplified to make code shorter.

Comment: That is too much simplification, to help you with the example i have to understand the data flow, meaning where a and b are actually read.

Comment: Edited the question to contain more information, sorry

Comment: I think you'll need to use `k` as an index for the inner for loop, and use it to index into `MachP`, instead of looping directly over `MachP`. Also (or maybe just instead), initialise `MachPoints` to a zero vector at the start of each iteration of the parfor loop.

Comment: With the updated example, it is now clear what you are doing and where you struggle. `MachPoints` is filled in the inner loop and then used. It is intended to be a temporary variable which each worker creates, uses and then never has to communicate. You make it a temporary variable fully initializing `MachPoints` within the parfor loop, for example using `nan`. For details: https://de.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html .

Comment: Im not sure that I understand what it means. I looked at the example but still not sure how to use. Any change for small example of using this inner loop inside parfor?